# How do I fetch the names of the classes scanned by .flow_from_directory function of ImageDataGenerator in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I want to make a user friendly GUI image classifier where the user would just need to point to the directory of the data set to get the model trained and then they can give any image to the program and it will display the probability and label of the object in the image. But how do I get the names of the classes scanned by .flow_from_directory function of ImageDataGenerator in Keras?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation, "*The dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute `class_indices`.*"

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory

In the example below, the `train_data_dir` contains two sub-folders, `cat` and `dog`.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    shuffle = True,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

print(train_generator.class_indices)
{'cat': 0, 'dog': 1}
```

`